# Added wishlist to cart and stay on wishlist page

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, jquery

How to stay on page after add wishlist product to cart?

Here is the function

```
public function getJs()
{
    $js = "
        function addWItemToCart(itemId) {
            var url = '" . $this->getItemAddToCartUrl('%item%') . "';
            url = url.gsub('%item%', itemId);
            var form = $('wishlist-view-form');
            swal('Barang berhasil di tambahkan ke keranjang');
            if (form) {
                var input = form['qty[' + itemId + ']'];
                if (input) {
                    var separator = (url.indexOf('?') >= 0) ? '&' : '?';
                    url += separator + input.name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(input.value);
                }

            }
            setLocation(url)
        }
    ";

    $js .= parent::getJs();
    return $js;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override this `Mage_Wishlist_IndexController::addAction()` and replace this:

```
$this->_redirect('*', array('wishlist_id' => $wishlist->getId()));
```

to  `$this->_redirectReferer()`

Comment: can you guide me where is the path of file "Mage_Wishlist_IndexController::addAction()"?

Comment: app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php

Comment: That is work. But when i checked my wishlist, there are no products. Can you solve it?